# how assign values to variables in racket?

Tags: scheme, variable-assignment, racket

if I have this list

```
'((x 3) (y 4) (z 2))
```

how do I assign 3 to x and y to 4 and z to 2 to use it to do math like?

```
3 + x
```

or

```
y + z
```

Thanks

Comment: The first part of your question suggests you really want a list with quoted symbols, but the second part suggest you don't know much about s-exps and therefore that you may be after a much simpler answer. If the latter is true, what you want is the first part of Oscar's answer about `let`, and don't look at the second part.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `let` to declare local variables in Scheme. For example, to create bindings with the given values in the list:

```
(let ((x 3) (y 4) (z 2))
  (+ y z)) ; body

=> 6
```

Now you can evaluate any expression involving the declared variables in the `<body>` part. You can even create a `let` from a list of bindings, for instance using macros:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(define-syntax my-let
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ lst exp)
     (eval `(let ,lst ,exp) ns)]))

(my-let '((x 3) (y 4) (z 2)) ; bindings as an association list
        '(+ y z))            ; expression to be evaluated

=> 6
```

The above creates a macro called `my-let` which receives a list of bindings and an expression to be evaluated with those bindings, and returns the result of the evaluation.

Comment: It's early in the morning, my coffee mug is missing and I can't think of a way to avoid using `eval`, so suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Just for the sake of it, you can have this syntax rule: `[(_ (quote lst) exp) ....]` where `quote` is a literal, but of course this is somewhat cheating ;) 
(Though your `my-let` will not work either if the list is first assigned to a variable and given to `my-let`.)

Comment: @Metaxal I modified a bit my code so that `lst` and `exp` can now be passed as variables, as long as `exp` is a quoted expression

Answer (score 2):

A simple, straightforward and portable way would be to define an accessor (in this example, *getval*) using `assq`:

```
(define vars '((x 3) (y 4) (z 2)))
(define (getval sym) (cadr (assq sym vars)))
```

or any variation thereof. Then use as follows:

```
(+ 3 (getval 'x))
=> 6

(+ (getval 'y) (getval 'z))
=> 6
```